# How to search using LIKE including whitespaces and only spaces?

Tags: mysql

I have a recipe table containing id,recipe_name,recipe_ingredients fields.I am joining these  tables in order to search a particular recipe.

My question:"How can i search Veg Noodles, Easy Noodles etc using just "noodles" in like query?

My query:

```
SELECT r.*,l.*,CASE WHEN (COUNT(l.recipe_id)=0)THEN 0 ELSE 1  END as like_status,
  u.name,u.user_image,u.location,u.contact_no,COUNT(l.recipe_id) as total_likes
FROM recipe as r
  LEFT JOIN likes as l ON r.recipe_id = l.recipe_id
  LEFT JOIN user_detail as u ON r.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE r.recipe_name LIKE '%$search%'
```

Above query of mine returns only the data containing "noodles".I have tried replacing spaces using replace in above query,but not a luck.So how can I search using LIKE including all whitespaces and spaces?

Comment: It doesn't care about whitespace. Are you sure it's not about case sensitivity? `LOWER(r.recipe_name) like '%$search%'`

Answer (score 0):

We can use like these

```
select * from table_name where table_name like "%Veg Noodles%"
```

These SQL is useful i think

Thank you.